# Snowflake Web UI - Query History - no colored breakdown of Bytes Scanned

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I noticed a strange thing in Snowflake Web UI - see description below.

The History tab has a nice feature: colored breakdown of columns Duration, Bytes, Rows that show, for example, where results came from (Bytes).

The strange thing: the colored breakdown disappears (i.e. only numbers are shown) when I filter the view by USER, and set the value to myself (i.e. I'm exploring my own queries).

The coloring comes back for all other cases: either filter on anything other than USER, or specify a different User's queries.

Anybody else seen the same?

Comment: Sounds like either a browser glitch or all of your queries are super-fast so there is nothing to breakdown.

Comment: I'm voting to close - unless there's additional information that could help others help here.

Comment: Sounds interesting to me. Was Mike's comment correct? Could be a reason...